# Selenium - switch to div class that is a window

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need help selecting an element on a webpage with Selenium. I have been using Selenium on this website for about 3 weeks and so far, I can usually find an element by css selector or XPath. However, this specific section of the website is giving me a very hard time.
After I click on “reset office 365 password” a window comes up and I want to programmably put in the new password but it can’t find anything in the popup window.
Here is what the page looks like:
(I am too low of score to post pictures here) https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/768594779344470022/845811910577881098/unknown.png

Here is the whole element’s information:

```
<input type="password" tabindex="1" name="password" class="m-third pass ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="password.value" ng-blur="password.check = false" ng-focus="password.check = true" required="" autofocus="" ng-disabled="!active">
```

**Here is what I tried: (I tried a lot of things)**

Tried clicking on the password box by using css selector – failed: Invalid selector

```
im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ng-app > div.page-container > div > div > div.vertical-tabs.j-vertical-tabs.ng-scope > div.vertical-tabs-panes.p0 > div > div > div.page-content.ng-scope > div > div > form > div > div > div.ng-isolate-scope > div.modal > div.modal-body.ng-transclude > div > reset:password > ng-form > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.validation-input > input')
 im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Tried clicking on the password box by using xpath selector – failed: Namespace Error

```
im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/reset:password/ng-form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
```

```
NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/reset:password/ng-form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input' contains unresolvable namespaces.
```

Tried waiting for the element by partial link text: It timed out

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Generate password')))
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Tried waiting for the element by ID name text value: It timed out

```
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn m-link'), "Generate Password"))
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Tried to switch to a window or iframe but it said that the div class of "model" is not a window or an iframe.

From here I am completely lost as to why this stupid window is not accessible. Text window - why are you so mean to me?

Here is my specific function in total:

```
def reset_im_oa_password():
    browser_options.browser.get('https://cpx.intermedia.net/ControlPanel/Menu/AccountMenu/?frameUrl=https://cpx.intermedia.net/aspx/Office365/Home/licenses#/installed/users')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 10)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'player')))
    except exceptions.TimeoutException as e:
        pass

    browser_options.browser.switch_to_frame('mainFrame')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ng-app > div.page-container > div > div > div.vertical-tabs.j-vertical-tabs.ng-scope > div.vertical-tabs-panes.p0 > div > div > div.page-content.ng-scope > div > div > form > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.table-wrap.table-fixed.j-table-wrap.s-wide.ng-isolate-scope > div.table-filter > div.table-filter-search.searchbox.ng-isolate-scope > div > span:nth-child(3) > input')))
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ng-app > div.page-container > div > div > div.vertical-tabs.j-vertical-tabs.ng-scope > div.vertical-tabs-panes.p0 > div > div > div.page-content.ng-scope > div > div > form > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.table-wrap.table-fixed.j-table-wrap.s-wide.ng-isolate-scope > div.table-filter > div.table-filter-search.searchbox.ng-isolate-scope > div > span:nth-child(3) > input')
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_or_user_selection.email_select)
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ng-app > div.page-container > div > div > div.vertical-tabs.j-vertical-tabs.ng-scope > div.vertical-tabs-panes.p0 > div > div > div.page-content.ng-scope > div > div > form > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.table-wrap.table-fixed.j-table-wrap.s-wide.ng-isolate-scope > div.table-filter > div.table-filter-search.searchbox.ng-isolate-scope > div > span:nth-child(3) > button')
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//*[starts-with(@id, 'btnResetPassword')]"))))
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[starts-with(@id, 'btnResetPassword')]"))
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Generate password')))
    except exceptions.TimeoutException as e:
        pass
    browser_options.browser.switch_to_window('model') # anything past this section will fail
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'model')))
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/reset:password/ng-form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
   
    return
```

**if anyone needs the full code from the webpage let me know. Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this element is not really inside an iframe as you write, then, wait for it to become clickable, like this:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']")))
im_blacklistaddbutton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")
im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys("new_password")
```

But make sure that css selector `input[type='password']` is unique.
If not, try this one: `.validation-input>input[type='password']`
(Check `validation-input` class name si correct as it is cut on your screenshot)

2. If the input frame is inside iframe nothing will work until you switch to this iframe.

Comment: I literally just tried the `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']")))` and it worked flawlessly. I don't know how you were able to determine to use this `input[type='password']` for the css selector. Every time I copied and pasted the css selector from selenium chrome browser it always gave me this: `too long to allow post :(`. If you can explain how you got to `input[type='password']` that would be most helpful. Either way, you solved my issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: input - tag name,  type-its attribute. password - its value. I saw it on your screenshot.

Comment: Praise the heavens for screenshots! JK lol. Ah that is interesting. So I can used css selector with a tag name and its attribute defined? That is awesome to know. I will book mark this for future refence. I don't know much about css selectors so I was always told to copy it from the inspector within chrome or firefox. But this this knowledge, I can look at the element and try different tags with its attributes. Thank you again. This is the type of vital stuff I need to know in my life.

Answer (score 0):

Because of no webpage code, right now I can't say why the element is not detectable by Selenium but you can try one thing. Right click on the element(input tag in dom shown in picture) and go to "Copy to" option and select "Copy JS Path". Then go to console tab in dev tools and paste it. Then try to set it's value to some dummy text and see if it sets the password.

```
jsPath.value="some password"  //this should set the password
```

If this works, then you can set the value by using JavaScript executor of Selenium in the same way.